# How to return the appended element back to input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When I click on the edit button, I want to edit the table data in the inputs.

the rest of the code is correct only thing that I need Is I want to edit the table data in the inputs

sorry for my bad english.

When I click on the edit button, I want to edit the table data in the inputs.

the rest of the code is correct only thing that I need Is I want to edit the table data in the inputs

sorry for my bad english.

```js
var myContacts = [];
        $(document).ready(function () {
            let btn = $("#btn-1");
            let btn2 = $("#btn-2");
            let btn3 = $("#btn-3");

            btn.click(function () {
                let name = $("#name");
                let age = $("#age");
                let job = $("#job");
                let address = $("#address");
                let mobile = $("#mobile");
                if (name.val().length > 0 && age.val().length > 0 && job.val().length > 0 && address.val().length > 0 && mobile.val().length > 0) {
                    contacts = {
                        name: name.val(),
                        age: age.val(),
                        job: job.val(),
                        address: address.val(),
                        mobile: mobile.val()
                    }
                    myContacts.push(contacts)
                }else{
                    alert("plz fill the form")
                };
                document.getElementById("name").value = "";
                document.getElementById("age").value = "";
                document.getElementById("job").value = "";
                document.getElementById("address").value = "";
                document.getElementById("mobile").value = "";
                console.log(myContacts);
            });
            btn2.click(function () {
                showMyContacts(myContacts);
            });
            let btnRem = $(".btn_remove");
            $(document).on('click', ".btn_remove", function () {
                let index = $(this).data("index");
                myContacts.splice(index, 1);
                showMyContacts(myContacts);
            });
            let btnEddit = $(".btn_edit");
            $(document).on('click', ".btn_remove", function () {
                
            });
        });
        function showMyContacts(myContacts) {
            let table = $("#my_table tbody");
            table.html("");
            for (let i = 0; i < myContacts.length; i++) {
                table.append(`
                <tr>
                    <td>${myContacts[i].name}</td>
                    <td>${myContacts[i].age}</td>
                    <td>${myContacts[i].job}</td>
                    <td>${myContacts[i].address}</td>
                    <td>${myContacts[i].mobile}</td>
                    <td><button data-index="${i}" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">Remove</button></td>
                    <td><button data-index="${i}" class="btn btn-primary btn_edit">Edit</button></td>
                </tr>
                `);
            };
        };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container m-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <span>Name :</span>
                <input id="name" type="text" class="d-flex mb-3">
                <span>Age :</span>
                <input id="age" type="number" class="d-flex mb-3">
                <span>Job :</span>
                <input id="job" type="text" class="d-flex mb-3">
                <span>Address :</span>
                <input id="address" type="text" class="d-flex mb-3">
                <span>Mobile :</span>
                <input id="mobile" type="tel" class="d-flex mb-3">
                <button id="btn-1" class="mt-2">Save</button>
                <button id="btn-2" class="mt-2">my Contacts</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <table id="my_table" class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>Job</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>Mobile</th>
                            <th>action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: A workaround instead of placing `<input>`s would be make each `<td>` be `contenteditable=true` when Edit is clicked.

Comment: why don't you use a **real** form ?

Comment: Poor English is no excuse for essentially repeating the same sentence numerous times

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after, allows you to edit and save changes to each row, it's not the best code ever, just something I thew together quickly

```js
let myContacts = [];
let edit = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  let btn = $("#btn-1");
  let btn2 = $("#btn-2");
  let btn3 = $("#btn-3");

  btn.click(function() {
    let name = $("#name");
    let age = $("#age");
    let job = $("#job");
    let address = $("#address");
    let mobile = $("#mobile");
    if (name.val().length > 0 && age.val().length > 0 && job.val().length > 0 && address.val().length > 0 && mobile.val().length > 0) {
      contacts = {
        name: name.val(),
        age: age.val(),
        job: job.val(),
        address: address.val(),
        mobile: mobile.val()
      }
      myContacts.push(contacts)
    } else {
      alert("plz fill the form")
    };
    document.getElementById("name").value = "";
    document.getElementById("age").value = "";
    document.getElementById("job").value = "";
    document.getElementById("address").value = "";
    document.getElementById("mobile").value = "";
    console.log(myContacts);
  });
  btn2.click(function() {
    showMyContacts(myContacts);
  });
  let btnRem = $(".btn_remove");
  $(document).on('click', ".btn_remove", function() {
    let index = $(this).data("index");
    myContacts.splice(index, 1);
    showMyContacts(myContacts);
  });
  let btnEddit = $(".btn_edit");

  $(document).on('click', ".btn_edit", function() {
    if ($(this).text() === "Edit") {
      $(this).text("Save")
      $(this).closest("tr").find("td").each(function(index) {
        if (index < 5)
          $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
      })
    } else {
      let data = []
      $(this).text("Edit")
      var values = $(this).closest("tr").text()
        .replace("Remove", "").replace("Edit", "")
        .replace(/\r/g, "").split(/\n/);
      jQuery.map(values, function(n, i) {
        if ($.trim(n) !== "") {
          data.push($.trim(n))
        }
      })
      contacts = {
        name: data[0],
        age: data[1],
        job: data[2],
        address: data[3],
        mobile: data[4]
      }
      myContacts[$(this).attr("data-index")] = contacts
      console.log(myContacts)
      $(this).closest("tr").find("td").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'false');
      })
    }
  });
});

function showMyContacts(myContacts) {
  let table = $("#my_table tbody");
  table.html("");
  for (let i = 0; i < myContacts.length; i++) {
    table.append(`
                <tr>
                    <td>${myContacts[i].name}</td>
                    <td>${myContacts[i].age}</td>
                    <td>${myContacts[i].job}</td>
                    <td>${myContacts[i].address}</td>
                    <td>${myContacts[i].mobile}</td>
                    <td><button data-index="${i}" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">Remove</button></td>
                    <td><button data-index="${i}" class="btn btn-primary btn_edit">Edit</button></td>
                </tr>
                `);
  };
};
```

```html
       
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container m-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <span>Name :</span>
                <input id="name" type="text" class="d-flex mb-3">
                <span>Age :</span>
                <input id="age" type="number" class="d-flex mb-3">
                <span>Job :</span>
                <input id="job" type="text" class="d-flex mb-3">
                <span>Address :</span>
                <input id="address" type="text" class="d-flex mb-3">
                <span>Mobile :</span>
                <input id="mobile" type="tel" class="d-flex mb-3">
                <button id="btn-1" class="mt-2">Save</button>
                <button id="btn-2" class="mt-2">my Contacts</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <table id="my_table" class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>Job</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>Mobile</th>
                            <th>action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I hope this helps https://jsfiddle.net/kegh286u/